# "ViewManagerAdapter_ExpoAdsAdMobBannerView" was not found in the UIManager

Tags: admob, banner-ads

i am facing this error while trying to embed the admob banner in my code.

The native view manager required by name (ExpoAdsAdMobBannerView) from NativeViewManagerAdapter isn't exported by expo-modules-core. Views of this type may not render correctly. Exported view managers: [ExpoLinearGradient, ExpoBarCodeScannerView, ExpoVideoView, ExponentGLView, ExponentCamera].

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Expo SDK 46, the `expo-ads-admob` package is deprecated. You should use `react-native-google-mobile-ads` instead. See [Expo docs here](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/v45.0.0/sdk/admob/).

Comment: but when i use ```react-native-google-mobile-ads``` it ask me to link react-native with react-native-google-mobile-ads by running ```react-native link react-native-google-mobile-ads```. after running it shows ```error: unknown command 'link'```. because react-native link is not supported with expo. how can i solve it .

Answer (score -1):

In my case it was

`"react-native-google-mobile-ads": { "android_app_id": "ca-app-pub-9152919921144751~8976099674", "ios_app_id": "ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxx~xxxxxxxx" } }`

Then i fix by removing ios_app_id